# Google autocomplete is not working How to resolve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

```
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
    var componentForm = {
        street_number: 'short_name',
        route: 'long_name',
        locality: 'long_name',
        administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
        country: 'long_name',
        postal_code: 'short_name'
    };

    function initialize1() {
        // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search
        // to geographical location types.
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
            /** @type {HTMLInputElement} */
            (document.getElementById('cityzip')), {
                types: ['geocode']
            });
        // When the user selects an address from the dropdown,
        // populate the address fields in the form.
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
            console.log(autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location);
        });
    }
```

Please help me why it not displaying auto suggestion and why it not displaying lat and long in console. How can I resolve this please help me. Sorry for grammatical and spelling mistakes.

Comment: Post the https://jsfiddle.net/ link for your example.

Comment: How are you including the Google Maps Javascript API v3?  Are you including the places library?  Is it enabled for your key? Please provide a [mcve] (**in the question itself**) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: After all of @geocodezip's questions are answered — and please, in the question, *not* on jsFiddle or another external site — are there any errors in your [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Answer (score 0):

May be you are not including the google maps javascript correct. Please including the places library
Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

you can check the place library by: `console.log(google.maps.places);`
and this is example on jsfiddle.net. 
I hope it helpful with you.

https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/GVdK6/

https://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/f9akomrd/